# jQuery Skrollr plugin: using skrollr constants as data values

Tags: jquery, skrollr

Is it possible to use `constants` (which are actually not constants) for values, too?
For ex:

```
<div data-_foo="_bar"></div>
```

and

```
skrollr.init({
   constants: {
     foo: function () { return 500; },
     bar: function() { return 'top: 200px';}
   }
});
```

A use case would be for example when the animation values depends on the screen size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, actually can be easily resolved with changing the values of the data-_foo on resize. 1 step more is not so much...